# How to proxy https to http and enable ssl?

Tags: http, ssl, nginx, websocket, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have configured my app to communicate via WebSocket (WS) protocol and I want to load the app over `https`. I'm getting the following error after setting up the SSL using `Nginx`:

> Mixed Content: The page was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint.

After some research, I could redirect `HTTPS` to `HTTP` using the `redirect` directive from `Nginx`. However, it loads the app over `HTTP` (without SSL). I want to enable SSL as well.

After some further research, I'm trying to proxy `https` with the following configurations:

```
server {
           listen 443;
           server_name my.server.com;

            ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/fullchain.pem;
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/privkey.pem; 
            include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; 
            ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; 
         
           ssl on;
           ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            

            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
            proxy_read_timeout 86400;       
         
        }
    }

server {
    listen 8000;
       
    root /home/ubuntu/app;
    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html;

}
```

But, I'm still getting the same "Mixed content" error.

Is there a way to proxy/redirect the `HTTPS` to `HTPP` while enabling the SSL?

Many thanks

**Updated**

Inside my app, I'm setting using the ws endpoint like this:

```
const web3 = new Web3 ('ws://server-ip:7546')
```

Note: I can't use `const web3 = new Web3 ('wss://server-ip:7546')`

I have updated `Nginx` configs like this to proxy the above-mentioned ws endpoint:

```
server {
           listen 443;
           server_name my.app.com;

           root /home/ubuntu/app;
           index index.html;

           ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/fullchain.pem;
           ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/privkey.pem; 
           include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; 
           ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
         
           ssl on;
           ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;


        location / {
            
           proxy_pass http://server-ip:7546;
           
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
           proxy_set_header Host $host;

        }

    }
```

I'm using the same `server-ip` in my app and `proxy_pass`.
any help what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The error your get cannot be solved in your server configuration.

It comes from accessing a plain HTTP or WS resource from inside a site served by HTTPS. **Thus it is a problem by the actual content you serve and need to be fixed there**. While the redirect you try might ultimately redirect the insecure access to a secure access it does not change that it will first need to do the insecure access already, which is already blocked due to mixed content.

Comment: is there a way to proxy the ws endpoint? inside `location` directive, I'm trying `proxy_pass http://ws-endpoint` but still no luck.

Comment: @Yahya: this is actually pretty common and [well documented](https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/) on how to do this.

Comment: thanks, can you please check the updated part of the question?

Comment: @Yahya: please stop making your question a moving target. But since you now reverse proxied your websocket you of course need to access it through the reverse proxy (i.e. `wss://proxy/` and not directly as before.

Comment: sorry, I could not get. Can you please explain a bit more where/how to use `wss://proxy/`?

Comment: @Yahya: *"Inside my app, I'm setting using the ws endpoint like this:

`const web3 = new Web3 ('ws://server-ip:7546')`"* - There. Your app should access the websocket over the reverse proxy but currently it does not.